# How can I use linq-to-sql with references?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I use Entity Framework 6, and derived my model from the database. I did not set the option to "include foreign keys columns".

I can add new entities to this model, to set the foreign key references I use a reference to the other object, like this:

```
client.Country = country;
```

When trying to query the model using references I encounter a problem:

```
ctx.Client.Where(c => c.Country == country);
```

results in an error "Unable to create constant value of type "country type". Only primitive types are supported".

Using the numeric id of the foreign key

```
ctx.Client.Where(c => c.id_Country == country.idCountry);
```

cannot work, as I chose not to include the foreign key columns.

---

I found an ugly workaround by loading it all to memory and filtering there, using the reference

```
List<Client> clients = ctx.Clients.ToList();
clients.Where(c => c.Country == country);
```

but that is not very elegant.

Any idea? Including the foreign keys is easiest, obviosuly, but the model looks so much cleaner without.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[reference property].[key property]` for that, e.g.

```
c => c.Country.id_Country == country.idCountry
```

EF is smart enough to recognize it as FK property accessor inside LINQ to Entities queries and translate it to the FK column name.

In other words, in L2E query `c.Country.id_Country` is the same as `c.id_Country` FK property if it existed.